# Lines perpendicular to vectors- are they similar triangles?

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

Please excuse my horrible vector drawing skills.

[image]

Let us first assume that we have a third vector, called $\Delta V = V_2 - V_1$  Now, these three vectors make a triangle, $V_1, V_2, \Delta V$.  Let us call this triangle 1.  Please note that the angle between these two vectors ($V_1, V_2$ can be any value from 0 to 90 degrees)

If we have a vector perpendicular to $V_1$, let us call it $A_1$ and a vector perpendicular to $V_2$, let us call it $A_2$, and we have a third vector called $\Delta A = A_2 - A_1$.  Now, these three vectors make a triangle, called triangle 2,  $A_1, A_2, \Delta A$

My question is, will triangle 2 be a *similar* triangle to triangle 1?

EDIT: Sorry for drawing improper vectors.  The *arrow tip* of each vector will be the highest value possible for the x-axis.  That is, the tip for both vectors is at the end of the far right of the vector.  IN other words, vectors $V_1, V_2$ are joined together TAIL TO TAIL.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, it depends on the lengths of $\mathbf{A}_1$ and $\mathbf{A}_2$ The ratio of the side lengths of similar triangles are equal. If you do have the correct ratio then by perpendicularity the angles between the two pairs of sides are the same and the triangles will be similar.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention this in the question.  The vectors $V_1, V_2$ are both equal.  Also, their perpendicular lines are also equal.